# best practice to store multiple inputs value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, typescript, algorithm

I have created an asp.net web API project with angular in the front-end.
I have to create a model like this :

[image]

but using a formGroup in typeScript will cost a lot of time and energy, same in the backend I have to create a +50 query to store the data.

```
this.formGroup=this.fb.group({

  siloA1:['',Validators.required],
  siloA2:['',Validators.required],
  siloA3:['',Validators.required],
  siloA4:['',Validators.required],
  siloA5:['',Validators.required],
  siloA6:['',Validators.required],
 .............
```

in the service .net I have to repeat this code for every input :

```
shiftTranferStatusAdded = new ShiftTranferStatus
                    {
                        subsystemId = option.silo,
                        unitId = option.unite_id
                    };
                    shiftTranferAdded = _dbContext.shiftTranfers.Add(shiftTranferAdded);
```

Which are the steps to follow to achieve that?

Comment: Maybe. Form array is a better approach here? And if not, you should be able to easily generate the controls automatically in a loop.

Comment: I thought on this but i found that if I can create a list inside the formbuilder like this : `silo:this.fb.array([])` and the value of the input is : "the value entry + silo + unite" and in the backend I will just create a switch case inside loop

Comment: If you want to mannage an array of arrays, you should use a FormArray of FormArrays In this [a bit old SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59223972/create-dynamic-mat-table-like-math-matrix-with-angular-material/59234386#59234386) I mannage it using mat-table.

Comment: NOTE: in older versions of Angular you could iterate over formArray.controls and use the variable witch you use to iterate, but since Angular 9 it's not possible. So, when we has a FormArray of formArray you has a "getter" of the outer FormArray and a function to get the inner formArray, like this [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734864/i-am-not-able-to-create-a-formarray-inside-formarray-dynamically-when-i-call-get/63736230#63736230)

Comment: As mentioned by colleagues above, the easiest way is to use dynamic form building based on arrays & form groups: the idea is to store every [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) with a property name of "slot_(i+1)" (where "i" is the index of the newly created FormGroup) on an [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray), personally i use [this reference](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/) for this kind of data manipulations